# Wordpress: Adding Google Analytics onClick in plugin ($content)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I want to add this line to my Wordpress plugin to track forms submits in Google Analytics:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Get Solutions', 
eventAction: 'Set    Reminder', eventLabel: 'Activated Reminder'});"
```

I implemented it like this:

```
$content .= '<input type="submit" name="sch_submit" value="Set reminder"   
style="background:#1eaa2f" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Get 
Solutions', eventAction: 'Set Reminder', eventLabel: 'Activated Reminder'});">
```

However, I am now confronted with the following error.

```
´Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/test/public_html/
 wp-content/plugins/schedule-reminder/plugin.php on line 70´
```

Thus, I am wondering how can I track form submits with Google Analytics from within my plugin code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the single-quote with a backslash, otherwise you tell PHP that the string reached the end, while it didn't.

```
$content .= '<input type="submit" name="sch_submit" value="Set reminder"   
style="background:#1eaa2f" onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', { eventCategory: \'Get 
Solutions\', eventAction: \'Set Reminder\', eventLabel: \'Activated Reminder\'});">';
```

Comment: Could you adjust the code and insert the backslash? I am not sure how to follow your instruction (e.g. where to insert the backslash). Thank you!